# How to dynamically change arrayname?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Test Case in Soap UI.

```
1. Datasource feeded for all operators
2. Login call
3. Search List call
4. Verify the search list for each operator



//Defining the SearchList for UserRole
String[] operator1= ["xx","yy","zz","aa"]
String[] operator2= ["bb","cc","dd"]
String[] operator3 = ["bb","cc","aa"]

To Verify the response based on operator I am using below code. 

//Extract Reponse and count of nodes
/*
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
respXml=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("SearchList#ResponseAsXml")
count=Integer.parseInt(respXml["count(//Response[1]/e)"]) */

//Extract Role from 
def role = context.expand( '${DataSource#Role}' )
log.info(role)


    for(i=1; i<=count;i++){
    element1=role[i-1]  
    log.info(element1)
    }
```

I am expecting to print"xx","yy","zz","aa" when role is operator1, but unfortunately it prints opeartor1 in different length.. How to dynamically pass the use role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example make the operators a map like

```
def operators = [
    operator1: ["xx","yy","zz","aa"],
    operator2: ["bb","cc","dd"],
    operator3: ["bb","cc","aa"]
]
```

and then retrieve the respective list by using `operators."$role"` or `operators[role]`. (If `role` is not a String you might need to do `operators["$role"]` or `operators[role as String]` in the latter case.